# How to find a record using a field other than id in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following code where I want to find a model using a field called link instead of id. However, it doesn't seem to produce any results. Where could I be getting it wrong? It returns 404

```
public function actionView($link)
    {
        $model = News::find()->where(['link'=>$link])->all();
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

NB: in the search model, I have tried adding this:

```
 $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'link'=>$this->link,
            'category' => $this->category,
            'date' => $this->date,
            'userid' => $this->userid,
            'featured' => $this->featured,
        ]);
```

Comment: check your url is correct

Comment: I'm using search friendly urls with a custom url manager like [link]http://localhost/project/frontend/web/controller/view/1  is working but
[link]http://localhost/project/frontend/web/controller/view/link is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may encounter such an error, the problem is after using pretty urls, you need to add rules to map the url format.
`C:\xampp\htdocs\your_project\frontend\config\main.php` under `urlManager` add the rules like so:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'news/view',
             '<controller:\w+>/<link>' => 'news/latestnews', // This is required for $link parameter
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<link>' => 'news/latestnews',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single model you need  one() and not all()

```
public function actionView($link)
{
    $model = News::find()->where(['link'=>$link])->one();
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

With one() method you retrive just a model  and in your $model  you have the data you need ..

If you sue all() lie you did you retrive a collection of models and for accessing  a single model you  must set a proper index eg:

```
$my_model = $model[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In UrlManager config you propably have:

```
'<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

It means default rewrite rules use `id` as param and it has to be digit, so you can't use `controller/view/link`. Just to be sure, change action name from `actionView` to `actionTest` and then call URL `controller/test?link=linklink`.

Other solution is to use URL like this: `controller/view?link=linklink`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your url

case 1)

http://localhost/projectName/backend/web/controllerName/actionName/username/rushil

Gives output : Not Found (#404)

case 2)

http://localhost/projectName/backend/web/controllerName/actionName/rushil

Gives output : Not Found (#404)

case 3)

http://localhost/projectName/backend/web/controllerName/actionName?username=rushil

this will work.

Solution : check your url and pass link parameter in url as shown in case 3

Answer (score 0):

404 means your action was not found by url manager. `link` parameter **must** be in the url (`http://yourapp/controller/view?link=something`) because you definded it as `actionView($link)`

Requesting `http://yourapp/controller/view` will give you 404 error.

Comment: It's working when i put `http://localhost/project/frontend/web/controller/view/1` but not when I put  `http://localhost/project/frontend/web/controller/view/parameter`